# Effect of culture on language

Tags: syntax, list-of-languages

What are some examples of cultures where the language spoken in that culture strongly reflects aspects of that culture

Comment: A language is part of a culture: it is part of my culture that I say "horse". It is part of Norwegian culture that they say "hest" for the same critter. Do you want more examples like that, or is that enough?

Comment: @user6726 i am more interested in aspects where differences in cultures cause differences in language. An example is that in Sanskrit,  “mountain” is associated with “challenge” due to Sanskrit flourishing in places bounded by mountains rather that in the top of mountains

Comment: "hest" vs. "horse" is a difference in language, so what makes my example not good enough. It seems that you need to be more specific in what you're looking for.

Comment: Start with [wiki sociolinguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sociolinguistics)